# Using regular expressions in R to extract information from string

Tags: regex, r

I searched the stack overflow a little and all I found was, that regex in R are a bit tricky and not convenient compared to Perl or Python.

My problem is the following. I have long file names with informations inside. The look like the following:

```
20150416_QEP1_EXT_GR_1234_hs_IP_NON_060.raw
20150416_QEP1_EXT_GR_1234-1235_hs_IP_NON_060.raw
20150416_QEP1_EXT_GR_1236_hs_IP_NON_060_some_other_info.raw
20150416_QEP1_EXT_GR_1237_hs_IP_NON_060
```

I want to extract the parts from the filename and convert them conveniently into values, for example the first part is a date, the second is machine abbreviation, the next an institute abbreviation, group abbreviation, sample number(s) etc...

What I do at the moment is constructing a regex, to make (almost) sure, I grep the correct part of the string:

```
regex <- '([:digit:]{8})_([:alnum:]{1,4})_([:upper:]+)_ etc'
```

Then I use `sub` to save each snipped into a variable:

```
date <- sub(regex, '\\1', filename)
machine <- sub(regex, '\\2', filename)
etc
```

This works, if the filename has the correct convention. It is overall very hard to read and I am search for a more convenient way of doing the work. I thought about splitting the filename by _ and accessing the string by index might be a good solution. But sometimes, since the filenames often get created by hand, there are terms missing or additional information in the names and I am looking for a better solution to this.

Can anyone suggest a better way of doing so?

**EDIT**

What I want to create is an object, which has all the information of the filenames extracted and accessible... such as `my_object$machine` or so....

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: From the example showed, it is not clear where the institute, group abbreviation starts/ends etc.  It would be better to show the expected result as @AvinashRaj mentioned

Comment: Every part is separated by _ so the string split solution would in general work... I just looking for some suggestions of better ways... In general I like the Python way, where you can directly define your variable names `re.match(r"(?P<first_name>\w+) (?P<last_name>\w+)", "Malcolm Reynolds")`

Comment: @akrun i think you already provided a solution of extracting and assigning the contents of captured groups into variables.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I think the OP doesn't want that kind of solution as there are some cases which don't follow the pattern.  Anyway, the OP seems to be not updating the expected output as per the data showed.  So, I am out..

Comment: yep, this part `But sometimes, since the filenames often get created by hand, there are terms missing or additional information in the names and I am looking for a better solution to this.`

Comment: By the way, what is OP? I am just looking for a more convenient way of splitting and extracting the data... As I suggested, I love the way of python, since you directly see the content (variable name) of the block. But I could not find a package in R to handle regex in a similar way. And alle the base and stringr methods are not easy to read...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help page for `?regex` actually gives an example that is exactly equivalent to Python's `re.match(r"(?P<first_name>\w+) (?P<last_name>\w+)", "Malcolm Reynolds")` (as per your comment):

> ```
> ## named capture
> notables <- c("  Ben Franklin and Jefferson Davis",
>               "\tMillard Fillmore")
> #name groups 'first' and 'last'
> name.rex <- "(?<first>[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+) (?<last>[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+)"
> (parsed <- regexpr(name.rex, notables, perl = TRUE))
> gregexpr(name.rex, notables, perl = TRUE)[[2]]
> parse.one <- function(res, result) {
>   m <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(res), function(i) {
>     if(result[i] == -1) return("")
>     st <- attr(result, "capture.start")[i, ]
>     substring(res[i], st, st + attr(result, "capture.length")[i, ] - 1)
>   }))
>   colnames(m) <- attr(result, "capture.names")
>   m
> }
> parse.one(notables, parsed)
> ```

The normal way (i.e. the R way) to extract from a string is the following:

```
text <- "Malcolm Reynolds"
x <- gregexpr("\\w+", text) #Don't forget to escape the backslash
regmatches(text, x)
[[1]]
[1] "Malcolm"  "Reynolds"
```

You can use however Perl-style group naming by using argument `perl=TRUE`:

```
regexpr("(?P<first_name>\\w+) (?P<last_name>\\w+)", text, perl=TRUE)
```

However `regmatches` does not support it, hence the need to create your own function to handle that, which is given in the help page:

```
parse.one <- function(res, result) {
       m <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(res), function(i) {
         if(result[i] == -1) return("")
         st <- attr(result, "capture.start")[i, ]
         substring(res[i], st, st + attr(result, "capture.length")[i, ] - 1)
       }))
       colnames(m) <- attr(result, "capture.names")
       m
     }
```

Applied to your example:

```
 text <- "Malcolm Reynolds"
 x <- regexpr("(?P<first_name>\\w+) (?P<last_name>\\w+)", text, perl=TRUE)
 parse.one(text, x)
     first_name last_name 
[1,] "Malcolm"  "Reynolds"
```

To go back to your initial problem:

```
filenames <- c("20150416_QEP1_EXT_GR_1234_hs_IP_NON_060.raw", "20150416_QEP1_EXT_GR_1234-1235_hs_IP_NON_060.raw", "20150416_QEP1_EXT_GR_1236_hs_IP_NON_060_some_other_info.raw", "20150416_QEP1_EXT_GR_1237_hs_IP_NON_060")
regex <- '(?P<date>[[:digit:]]{8})_(?P<machine>[[:alnum:]]{1,4})_(?P<whatev>[[:upper:]]+)'
x <- regexpr(regex,filenames,perl=TRUE)
parse.one(filenames,x)
     date       machine whatev
[1,] "20150416" "QEP1"  "EXT" 
[2,] "20150416" "QEP1"  "EXT" 
[3,] "20150416" "QEP1"  "EXT" 
[4,] "20150416" "QEP1"  "EXT"
```

Comment: I completely missed that part... I don't know why... Thanks also for the function `parse.one`. That looks like what I was thinking of... Will test this and maybe ask back in case of trouble!